# How can I extend my nav-bar to the edge of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar on my website http://rushycreekfarm.com.au/ that I want to extend to the edge of the screen (to the right of where it says CONTACT). I could simply have a h3 element with its padding-right set to 360px. But this would only work at full screen on a laptop/desktop. How can I do this more efficiently?

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rushy Creek Farm</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="details" class="header">765 Brockman Highway | 0438695434 | tracyrob@wallworks.com.au
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Rushy Creek Farm</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="./index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="./index.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="https://www.stayz.com.au/accommodation/wa/south- 
   west/augusta/9189326">BOOK</a>
    <a href="#details">CONTACT</a>
    <h3 style="padding-right: 360px"></h3>
  </div>
  <img id="arrow-left" class="arrow" src="./arrow-left.jpg">
  <img id="main-image" src="./images/droneshotcrop.jpg">
  <img id="arrow-right" class="arrow" src="./arrow-right.jpg">
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
<html>
`
```

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Mm... `style="float: right;"`  ?!

P.s. try `background-color: rgb(57, 97, 140);`  on button-hover))

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `nav-bar` is technically filling the width. One thing you could do is add `flex` to your `nav-bar` and space out your nav buttons.

```
.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

If you want the buttons to be wider instead of just spread out, you could just add `flex` to each of those `a` tags.

```
.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-bar a {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```